# MySQL batch queries with limit

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I need to change the ownership of several possessions in my MySQL table.  The thing that's tripping me up is that there are several identical goods and I don't want to change all of them.

Right now, I'm doing it with queries like this:

```
UPDATE possessions SET citizen_id=1 WHERE citizen_id=2 AND good_id=8 LIMIT 1
UPDATE possessions SET citizen_id=2 WHERE citizen_id=4 AND good_id=2 LIMIT 1
UPDATE possessions SET citizen_id=4 WHERE citizen_id=3 AND good_id=5 LIMIT 2
```

There are, some times, a lot of these and they're all so similar that I feel like there should be a way to submit them in a batch.  The examples I can find that show batch updates don't allow setting individual limits on each update like I need to.

Do you know of any way I can make this process faster?

Comment: You want a parallel update? Because some of sets will race with some of wheres. That could be undefined behaviour if they are to be done on the original data without using any temporary data. Can mysql do parallel updates without hard crossing multiple queries?

Comment: Using a temporary table is not out of the question.  I'm just looking for something to speed up this process when the number of updates runs into the hundreds or thousands.

Comment: Are these queries in a single sub function call? Or are you sending them one by one?

Comment: Currently, the only way I've found that gives me the correct results in to submit these queries one by one.

Comment: You are not using ORDER BY with your LIMITs, meaning you will be updating whatever row matches first. Is that intentional? Also, is the filter always on `citizen_id` and `good_id`? Finally, your examples include two LIMIT 1 updates and one LIMIT 2. Is that a typo or can LIMIT vary too?

Comment: @AndriyM Leaving out `ORDER BY` is intentional, it doesn't matter which match is changed.  Yes, the filter is always on `citizen_id` and `good_id`, there exist other fields in the possessions table, but none of them are relevant to this operation.  As for the number on the `LIMIT`, it can indeed be greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

The following method relies on the fact that the `possessions` table has a primary key and `citizen_id` is not part of it. Here's the idea:

1. Put all the parameters of the update (`citizen_id` and `good_id` to filter on, the new values of `citizen_id` and the numbers of rows to update) into some storage, a dedicated table, perhaps, or a temporary table.
2. Assign row numbers to `possessions` rows partitioning on `(citizen_id, good_id)`, then join the ranked row set to the parameter table to filter the original full set on `citizen_id` and `good_id`, as well as the number of rows.
3. Join `possessions` and the result of the previous join on the primary key values and update `citizen_id` with the new values.

In MySQL's SQL, the above might look like this:

```
UPDATE possessions AS p
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    @r := @r * (@c = p.citizen_id AND @g = p.good_id) + 1 AS r,
    p.possession_id,
    @c := p.citizen_id AS citizen_id,
    @g := p.good_id AS good_id
  FROM
    possessions AS p
  CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT @r := 0, @c := 0, @g := 0) AS x
  ORDER BY
    p.citizen_id,
    p.good_id
) AS f ON p.possession_id = f.possession_id
INNER JOIN
  possession_updates AS u ON u.citizen_id = f.citizen_id AND u.good_id = f.good_id
SET
  p.citizen_id = u.new_citizen_id
WHERE
  f.r <= u.row_count
;
```

The `possessions_update` is the table containing the parameter values.

The query uses a known method of row numbering that employs variables, which is implemented in the `f` subquery.

I don't have MySQL so I can't test this properly from the performance point of view, but at least you can see from [this SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f3e5/1) that the method works. (The UPDATE statement is in the schema script, because SQL Fiddle doesn't allow data modification statements in the right-side script for MySQL. The right side just returns the post-UPDATE contents of `possessions`.)