# MySQL: For each row in table, change one row in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I have two tables :

```
SELECT * FROM data;
+----+---+---+
| id | c | g |
+----+---+---+
|  1 | 1 | 2 |
|  2 | 1 | 2 |
|  3 | 1 | 2 |
|  4 | 1 | 3 |
|  5 | 2 | 2 |
|  6 | 2 | 3 |
|  7 | 2 | 3 |
+----+---+---+
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM changes;
+----+-------+-------+---+
| id | c_old | c_new | g |
+----+-------+-------+---+
|  1 |     1 |     2 | 2 |
|  2 |     2 |     1 | 3 |
|  3 |     1 |     2 | 2 |
+----+-------+-------+---+
```

For each row in `changes` I need to change exactly one row in `data` where `data.g=changes.g and data.c=changes.c_old`. (assume that there will always be enough matches)

I'm attempting to do this with this query:

```
UPDATE 
data INNER JOIN changes ON 
  data.c=changes.c_old AND p.g=changes.g 
SET data.c_id=changes.c_new 
WHERE data.id IN( 
  SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT data.id from 
    data INNER JOIN changes ON
      data.c=changes.c_old AND data.g=changes.g 
    GROUP BY changes.id
  ) AS another_table
)
```

Now, I'm surprised that that mess of a query runs at all.  But, it doesn't do what I need.  The innermost select returns this table:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  6 |
|  1 |
+----+
```

Notice that `1` appears twice.  That means only two rows got changed (or row 1 got changed twice) when I needed three to change.  Is there a way to make sure each id in that sub-query is unique?  Is there a better way to accomplish this mess?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting a field that is not part of the group by or being aggregated.

```
SELECT data.id from 
data INNER JOIN changes ON
    data.c=changes.c_old AND data.g=changes.g 
GROUP BY changes.id
```

You should use an aggregate function on the data.id in the select, or add data.id to the groupby (though I suspect that is not the result you want either)

The INNER JOIN is result in this dataset

```
+---------+--------+--------+------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
| data.id | data.c | data.g | changes.id | changes.c_old | changes.c_new | changes.g |
+---------+--------+--------+------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
|       1 |      1 |      2 |          1 |             1 |             2 |         2 |
|       1 |      1 |      2 |          3 |             1 |             2 |         2 |
|       2 |      1 |      2 |          1 |             1 |             2 |         2 |
|       2 |      1 |      2 |          3 |             1 |             2 |         2 |
|       3 |      1 |      2 |          1 |             1 |             2 |         2 |
|       3 |      1 |      2 |          3 |             1 |             2 |         2 |
|       6 |      2 |      3 |          2 |             2 |             1 |         3 |
|       7 |      2 |      3 |          2 |             2 |             1 |         3 |
+---------+--------+--------+------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
```

1,2,3 are expanded out due to multiple matches in the join, and 4,5 are eliminated due to no match

You then are grouping by changes.id, which is going to result in (showing with values in CSV list after grouping)

```
+---------+--------+--------+------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
| data.id | data.c | data.g | changes.id | changes.c_old | changes.c_new | changes.g |
+---------+--------+--------+------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
|   1,2,3 |  1,1,1 |  2,2,2 |          1 |         1,1,1 |         2,2,2 |     2,2,2 |
|   1,2,3 |  1,1,1 |  2,2,2 |          3 |         1,1,1 |         2,2,2 |     2,2,2 |
|     6,7 |    2,2 |    3,3 |          2 |           2,2 |           1,1 |       3,3 |
+---------+--------+--------+------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
```

Since no aggregate or deterministic way of choosing the values from the available options, you are getting the 1 from data.id chosen for both changes.id 1 and 3

Depending on what you are wanting, are you wanting 3 rows?  all distinct values?  you should add that deterministic behavior to the select.

btw, I am pretty sure other SQL engines would not allow that select (such as MSSQL) because its ambiguous.  As for MySQL behavior in that situation, I believe it chooses the first value from the first row stored, and thus why you probably get 1 in both cases, but it is free to choose whatever value it wishes.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values within each group the server chooses.

Comment: You have, perhaps, done a better job of asking my question than I did. I want each row in `changes` matched up with a different row in `data` .  So, the number of rows returned by the select should be equal to the number rows in `changes` and all values of data.id should be distinct.  I'm sorry that that wasn't more clear.  How to 'add that deterministic behavior to the select' would be the gist of my question.

Comment: I believe you are missing some data then in order to get that distinction.  The changes table is a tuple of (c.old, c.g) of which there are only 2 distinct values (1,2) and (2,3);  With the tuple (1,2) there are 3 matches in data, and for (2,3) there are 2 matches.  It sounds like you are saying for one of the matches of (1,2) you want to choose one id (for instance data.id = 1) and for another match choose a different one (for instance data.id = 2);  You would need a 3rd key to join on to cause that behavior (like a rowid)

Comment: Also, it seems you are using changes to track the changes of table data.  If that is the case, you should add a data.id to your changes table, and now you would have the distinct identifier to tie to back to the data record that changed. That could be your 3rd column to get your distinct row, though then there is no need to use the c.old and c.g columns for joining, because you have the primary key id of the data table in your changes table.

Are you attempting to track slowly changing dimensions or change in values of records in data?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. You have helped me think about my problem in more depth, even though I can't find a solution. I'm trying this out as a possible solutions to a this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21845372/mysql-batch-queries-with-limit), which I posted. The series of updates submitted individually produces the desired result, but is too slow.  I wanted to try 1. `create temporary table changes`, 2. `insert` all the changes as a batch, 3. perform this update, 4. `drop temporary table`. So, I don't know the `id`s of the rows I want to change.

Comment: You are going to have to get an unique identifier for what you want to update, especially if you are wanting to batch your updates.  You are essentially wanting to build a list of changes in a temporary table, and perform a batch update periodically from that table, opposed to running single update commands at a time.  You are saying you don't know the ids of the rows you want to change, but you are fine with just changing arbitrarily one of the instances of that tuple in data?  Why even allow duplicate instances in data if thats the case?

Comment: In reality, there are additional fields in `data` that make each row unique. In order to calculate my list of changes, I simplify the table to counts of these two fields. From the point of view of this operation, rows with the same `p` and `g` are identical, so changing one arbitrarily is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: instead of using "limit" to try to limit it to one update, I would use either rank or row_num.  you can use rank to give you an unique id for each instance of that tuple, and then you can do rank = 1 on the join, it will cause all the extra ones to go away, and your update would be limited to only the first instance

Comment: Thank you for discussing this with me.  My take away is that doing exactly what I want to here is impossible. I guess I need to either live with the bad performance that comes from submitting the updates one at a time, or redesign the system a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Let's divide the process into two tasks:

1. Getting the `id` of the rows to update in `data` and the value to set `c`.
2. Updating the values.

Task 1 can be achieved by the following query (note the use of `distinct` to get rid of duplicates):

```
select distinct d.id, c.c_new
from
    data as d
    inner join changes as c
        on  d.c = c.c_old
        and d.g = c.g
```

This should give you the following:

```
| id | c_new |
|----|-------|
|  1 |     2 |
|  2 |     2 |
|  3 |     2 |
|  6 |     1 |
|  7 |     1 |
```

Now for the update just use the previous query as a derived table expression and join it to `data`:

```
update
    data as da
    inner join (
        select distinct d.id, c.c_new
        from
            data as d
            inner join changes as c
            on  d.c = c.c_old
            and d.g = c.g
    ) as dc
    on da.id = dc.id
set d.c = dc.c_new;
```

And you are done, final result:

```
| ID | C | G |
|----|---|---|
|  1 | 2 | 2 |
|  2 | 2 | 2 |
|  3 | 2 | 2 |
|  4 | 1 | 3 |
|  5 | 2 | 2 |
|  6 | 1 | 3 |
|  7 | 1 | 3 |
```

Comment: That's much cleaner, but it's not actually any better.  Your select returned 5 lines which results in 5 `id`s in the `data` being changed.  There were only tree rows in `changes` so, only three rows in `data` need to be changed.